# Problema Formulario - Acho que colocaram um BOT

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou recebendo a cada 5 em 5 minutos 1 email vindo do meu formulário com as informação em números parecendo um tipo de BOT.

Estou usando o PHP MAILER

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

    if($_POST['nome'] != '' && $_POST['mensagem'] != ''){
        require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

        // Inicia a classe PHPMailer

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        // Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)

        $mail->Username = 'contato@somospixel.com'; // Username de acesso ao e-mail

        $mail->Password = '###'; // Senha do servidor SMTP

        // Define o remetente

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->From = "contato@somospixel.com"; // Seu e-mail
        $mail->FromName = "Contato Pixel"; // Seu nome

        // Define os destinatário(s)

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->AddAddress('contato@somospixel.com');
        $mail->AddReplyTo($email);

        // Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
        $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; // Charset da mensagem

         // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->Subject  = "Mensagem de Contato Pixel"; // Assunto da mensagem
        $mail->Body = "<font style=\"font-size:16px\"><b>Nome:</b> $nome; <br /><b>E-mail:</b> $email; <br /><b>Telefone:</b>$telefone; <br /><br /><b>Mensagem:</b><br />$mensagem</font>";
        $mail->AltBody = "Nome: $nome;\r\n E-mail: $email;\r\n\r\n Mensagem:\r\n $mensagem";
        // Envia o e-mail

        $enviado = $mail->Send();

        // Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();
    }
    header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem entrar em detalhes de código, creio que o ideal seria você fazer o seguinte:

**1º - Validar o envio com *captcha*:** Não precisa deixar em definitivo, mas implante e acompanhe por um período. Se realmente tem algum *bot* atacando sua página, isso deve resolver.

**2º - Validar com sessões ip + tempo de envio**: Uma solução "elegante" e que fica no *server* é validar o ip do usuário e um intervalo de tempo. Sugiro colocar que cada ip pode mandar 1 mensagem a cada 30 minutos, seria um tempo razoável.

**3º - Verifique seu server**: Precaução nunca é demais. Aproveite e verifique seu server, seus códigos. Veja se não tem nada "estranho". Pode ser que tenha algum script malicioso no seu projeto.

Com qualquer uma dessas sugestões seu problema deve ser resolvido.

Comment: estou pensando em colocar o captcha, mas antes alterei as variáveis para ver se cara esse spaw.
O metodo de validação, só vai atrasar o spaw para 30 a 30 minutos